# Prove that for any integer $a, a^{15}-a^3$ is divisible by $455$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

**The Problem**

Prove that for any integer $a, a^{15}-a^3$ is divisible by $455$.

Hint:  $455=5*7*13$. We proved that if $n$ is divisible by $x$, and $n$ is divisible by $y$, and $\gcd(x,y) = 1$, then $n$ is divisible by $x*y$. The upshot of this is that if $a^{15}-a^3$ is divisible by $5$, and by $7$, then it is divisible by $5*7=35$. And if $a^{15}-a^3$ is divisible by $5$, $7$, and $13$, then it is divisible by $5*7*13$. So you need to prove that $a^{15}-a^3$ is divisible by $5$, by $7$, and by $13$.

---

**Confusion**

My first guess was to try induction, although I wasn't sure if induction can even be used here since we are dealing with integers instead of natural numbers, so perhaps that is my first issue.  Even if this were a statement about natural numbers, I was still unable to figure out how induction could work here.

Secondly, the hint my instructor provided for this problem makes sense to me, but I haven't the slightest clue as to *how* to prove what's being asked.  For instance, how do we prove that $5|a^{15}-a^3$?  Induction seems to get us nowhere because you end up with $(k+1)^{15}-(k+1)^3$, and that seems like an insane amount of algebra.  There has to be something I'm missing here.

Any thoughts?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803097/prove-that-215-23-divides-a15-a3   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158766/show-that-7-divides-a15-a3-for-any-integer-a  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112666/show-that-a61-equiv-a-mod-1001-for-every-a-in-mathbbn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if we set $a^3=t$,  $$a^{15}-a^{3} \equiv t^{5}-t \equiv 0 \pmod {5}$$
By [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem), which says that $a^{p} \equiv a \pmod {p}$ if $p$ is prime. Furthermore, we notice that 
$$a^{15}-a^{3}=\color{blue}{(a^{7}-a)}(a^{8}+a^2) \equiv 0 \pmod {7}$$
Using Fermat's Little theorem when $p=7$, and similarly 
$$a^{15}-a^{3}=a^2 \times \color{orange}{(a^{13}-a)} \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$$
Hence, $a^{15}-a^{3}$ is divisible by $5$, $7$, and $13$, which implies that it is divisible by $5 \times 7 \times 13=455$. We are done.

If you truly want to use induction, see the [proof of Fermat's little theorem by Euler using induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Proof_using_the_binomial_theorem). You don't really need that much calculations, but it does require knowledge of the binomial theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly prompt and helpful answer.  I do have a follow up question, if you don't mind.  I understand the algebra performed in your answer, but how does $(a^7-a)(a^8+a^2)$ tell us that $a^{15}-a^3$ is divisible by $7$?  I suppose the connection to Fermat's Little Theorem still isn't clicking for me...

Comment: @ThyArtisMath If $a$ is divisible by $7$, then $ab$ is divisible by $7$. Note that $a^{7}-a$ is divisible by $7$.

Comment: Yep, that just clicked for me as soon as you replied!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would like establish how $15,3$ are identified and find a possible generalization of the same.

By Fermat's little theorem, prime $p$ divides $$a^p-a=a(a^{p-1}-1)$$

As $455=5\cdot7\cdot13$ where $5,7,13$ are pairwise prime, $455$ will divide

$$a(a^{\text{lcm}(5-1,7-1,13-1)}-1)=a(a^{12}-1)$$

hence will divide any multiple of $a(a^{12}-1)$