# Proving $364 \mid n^{91} - n^7$ [Generalization of Euler & Fermat Theorems]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I am trying to prove this statement which is equivalent to show $n^{91} = n^7 \pmod{ 364}$. By splitting modulus theorem $n^{91} = n^7 \bmod 91$ and $\bmod 4$. Then I don’t know what to do next... Can anyone help me?

Comment: note:  $91=7\times 13$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem):

Mod $4$:  either $n\equiv0 $ or $2$, so $n^{91}\equiv n^7\equiv0$, or $\color{blue}{n^2\equiv 1}$ so $n^{91}\equiv n^{84}n^7\equiv (n^2)^{42}n^7\equiv n^7$

Mod $7$:  either $n\equiv0$, so $n^{91}\equiv n^7\equiv 0$, or $\color{blue}{n^6\equiv 1}$ so $n^{91}\equiv n^{84}n^7\equiv(n^6)^{14}n^7\equiv n^7$

Mod $13$:  either $n\equiv0$, so $n^{91}\equiv n^7\equiv 0$, or $\color{blue}{n^{12}\equiv 1}$ so $n^{91}\equiv n^{84}n^7\equiv(n^{12})^{7}n^7\equiv n^7$

Comment: or could simply say $n^{12}\equiv 1\bmod 4, 7, $ and $13$

Comment: The argument is either incorrect or incomplete since it assumes $n$ is coprime to $\,4,7,13,\,$ but that is not assumed in the OP.

Comment: You are right; I thought of that at one point but then forgot; I will try to correct my answer

Comment: I edited my answer to include cases where $n$ is not coprime to $4, 7, 13$

Comment: With the fix, now it's a duplicate of the first proof in [this older answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408201/242), which further shows how it generalizes (leading to my answer here).

Answer (score 3):

It's a special case of below Euler-Fermat generalization with $\,e = 7,\, f = 84,\ \prod p_i^{e_i} =  2^2\cdot 7\cdot 13 $

**Theorem** $\  $ Suppose that $\ m\in \mathbb N\ $ has the prime factorization $\:m = p_1^{e_{1}}\cdots\:p_k^{e_k}\ $ and suppose that for all $\,i,\,$  $\  e_i\le e\ $ and $\ \phi(p_i^{e_{i}})\mid f.\ $ Then $\ m\mid a^e(a^f-1)\ $ for all $\: a\in \mathbb Z.$

**Proof** $\ $ If $\ p_i\mid a\ $ then $\:p_i^{e_{i}}\mid a^e\ $ by $\ e_i \le e.\: $ Else $\:a\:$ is coprime to $\: p_i\:$ so by Euler's phi theorem, $\!\bmod q = p_i^{e_{i}}\!: \ a^{\phi(q)}\equiv 1\,$ [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) $\,a^f\equiv 1\, $ by $\: \phi(q)\mid f.\ $  Since all $\ p_i^{e_{i}}\,$ divide $\, a^e (a^f - 1)\ $ so too does their product $\,m\,$ by [lcm = product for coprimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/696331/242), or by unique prime factorization.

**Examples** $\ $ You can find many illuminating examples in prior questions, e.g. below

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$24\mid a^3(a^2-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408201/242)

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$40\mid a^3(a^4-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/637468/242)

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$88\mid a^5(a^{20}\!-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1316052/242)

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$6p\mid a\,b^p - b\,a^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2003925/242)

Comment: So, we actually need any multiple of $$(n^2(n^2-1),n^7-n,n^{13}-n)=n^2(n^{12}-1)$$

Comment: @lab Yes, by the Theorem we can take $\, e = \max \{ e_i\} = 2,\ f = {\rm lcm} \{\phi(p_i^{e_i})\} = {\rm lcm}\{2,6,12\} = 12\ \ \ $